# How to increase height of Tableau dashboard

Tags: tableau-desktop

I'm trying to edit the embed code of a dashboard in Tableau. The height is 1000px but for some reason it crops off when placed HTML - see pic. How do I change it so it appears with full extent?

```
<div class='tableauPlaceholder' id='viz1700944984488' style='position: relative'><noscript><a href='#'><img alt='Price paid data ' src='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;Ho&#47;Housepricepaiddata&#47;Dashboard1&#47;1_rss.png' style='border: none' /></a></noscript><object class='tableauViz'  style='display:none;'><param name='host_url' value='https%3A%2F%2Fpublic.tableau.com%2F' /> <param name='embed_code_version' value='3' /> <param name='site_root' value='' /><param name='name' value='Housepricepaiddata&#47;Dashboard1' /><param name='tabs' value='no' /><param name='toolbar' value='yes' /><param name='static_image' value='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;Ho&#47;Housepricepaiddata&#47;Dashboard1&#47;1.png' /> <param name='animate_transition' value='yes' /><param name='display_static_image' value='yes' /><param name='display_spinner' value='yes' /><param name='display_overlay' value='yes' /><param name='display_count' value='yes' /><param name='language' value='en-GB' /></object></div>                <script type='text/javascript'>                    var divElement = document.getElementById('viz1700944984488');                    var vizElement = divElement.getElementsByTagName('object')[0];                    if ( divElement.offsetWidth > 800 ) { vizElement.style.width='800px';vizElement.style.minHeight='1027px';vizElement.style.maxHeight='1227px';vizElement.style.height=(divElement.offsetWidth*0.75)+'px';} else if ( divElement.offsetWidth > 500 ) { vizElement.style.width='800px';vizElement.style.minHeight='1027px';vizElement.style.maxHeight='1227px';vizElement.style.height=(divElement.offsetWidth*0.75)+'px';} else { vizElement.style.width='100%';vizElement.style.height='2227px';}                     var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');                    scriptElement.src = 'https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js';                    vizElement.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptElement, vizElement);                </script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a common scenario when you don't change the Dashboard Size on the Tableau desktop. Just Change it to a custom size like say 1100

[image: sample]

Tableau Public

[image]

Comment: I don't have those options on Tableau Public

Comment: Well you actually do : i added another image in my answer